# Quickbooks API App on AWS Lambda: OAuth only connects once

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, oauth-2.0, quickbooks-online

I am working with an AWS Lambda that connects to the QBO API.

My goal is to have this run via a lambda cron trigger once a day.

[Here is a gist of the oauth service I wrote >>](https://gist.github.com/donfiftyidaho/9b0222573bae2a809b9caad15624064f)

`intuit-oauth version: 3.0.2`

`Node.js version 12`

To get the OAuth started I get a fresh refresh token from the QBO playground and store that in a JSON file. After that I write the refresh token to the JSON file as it gets renewed. I've seen this work fine, I took about a week off from this project and the current refresh token in my JSON file got me access just fine when I came back to it. But this is only locally of course.

When I run test locally it works perfectly every time, after I deploy it to AWS it may work once or twice if I don't wait more than a few minutes to test. If I wait about 15 minutes I get the error below:

```
PopsicleError: Unable to connect to "https://oauth.platform.intuit.com/oauth2/v1/tokens/bearer"
    at Request.error (/var/task/node_modules/intuit-oauth/node_modules/popsicle/dist/request.js:41:16)
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/intuit-oauth/node_modules/popsicle/dist/index.js:131:39)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:326:22)
    at ClientRequest.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:483:12)
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:427:9)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:314:20)
    at TLSSocket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:483:12)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:92:8)
    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:60:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
  cause: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 54.148.164.32:443
      at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1144:16) {
    errno: 'ETIMEDOUT',
    code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
    syscall: 'connect',
    address: '54.148.164.32',
    port: 443
  },
  code: 'EUNAVAILABLE',
  popsicle: Request {
    Url: Url {
      protocol: 'https:',
      slashes: true,
      auth: null,
      host: 'oauth.platform.intuit.com',
      port: null,
      hostname: 'oauth.platform.intuit.com',
      hash: null,
      search: null,
      query: [Object: null prototype] {},
      pathname: '/oauth2/v1/tokens/bearer',
      path: '/oauth2/v1/tokens/bearer',
      href: 'https://oauth.platform.intuit.com/oauth2/v1/tokens/bearer'
    },
    rawHeaders: [
      'Authorization',
      'Basic QUJJd1JpUHdLVlFJcmhiUzJ6bjNvOXNWS2lHTHFuRk0yT2d4bHhXRlpHRWJ6Z1kyNlM6N2RsdUVIN1hKNE5Rb1JHbG1qWTFmZ0VvTGt4ZjdreHM1WjNVdmcxVA==',
      'Content-Type',
      'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      'Accept',
      'application/json',
      'User-Agent',
      'Intuit-OAuthClient-JS_3.0.2_Linux_4.14.209-112.339.amzn2.x86_64_linux',
      'Content-Length',
      '89',
      'Accept-Encoding',
      'gzip,deflate'
    ],
    middleware: [ [Function], [Function] ],
    opened: true,
    aborted: false,
    uploaded: 1,
    downloaded: 0,
    timeout: 0,
    method: 'POST',
    body: 'grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=AB11620585757X1ISX92Nj7a5o2kHSwY2nO7cKmcJYvcGND8Qu',
    events: [Object: null prototype] { abort: [Array] },
    transport: { use: [Array], abort: [Function: abort], open: [Function: open] },
    _promise: Promise { <rejected> [Circular] },
    _raw: ClientRequest {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 2,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      outputData: [],
      outputSize: 0,
      writable: true,
      _last: true,
      chunkedEncoding: false,
      shouldKeepAlive: false,
      _defaultKeepAlive: true,
      useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
      sendDate: false,
      _removedConnection: false,
      _removedContLen: false,
      _removedTE: false,
      _contentLength: null,
      _hasBody: true,
      _trailer: '',
      finished: true,
      _headerSent: true,
      socket: [TLSSocket],
      connection: [TLSSocket],
      _header: 'POST /oauth2/v1/tokens/bearer HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
        'Authorization: Basic QUJJd1JpUHdLVlFJcmhiUzJ6bjNvOXNWS2lHTHFuRk0yT2d4bHhXRlpHRWJ6Z1kyNlM6N2RsdUVIN1hKNE5Rb1JHbG1qWTFmZ0VvTGt4ZjdreHM1WjNVdmcxVA==\r\n' +
        'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n' +
        'Accept: application/json\r\n' +
        'User-Agent: Intuit-OAuthClient-JS_3.0.2_Linux_4.14.209-112.339.amzn2.x86_64_linux\r\n' +
        'Content-Length: 89\r\n' +
        'Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate\r\n' +
        'Host: oauth.platform.intuit.com\r\n' +
        'Connection: close\r\n' +
        '\r\n',
      _keepAliveTimeout: 0,
      _onPendingData: [Function: noopPendingOutput],
      agent: [Agent],
      socketPath: undefined,
      method: 'POST',
      insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
      path: '/oauth2/v1/tokens/bearer',
      _ended: false,
      res: null,
      aborted: true,
      timeoutCb: null,
      upgradeOrConnect: false,
      parser: null,
      maxHeadersCount: null,
      reusedSocket: false,
      host: 'oauth.platform.intuit.com',
      protocol: 'https:',
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
      [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype]
    },
    uploadLength: 89,
    uploadedBytes: 89
  },
  error: 'Unable to connect to "https://oauth.platform.intuit.com/oauth2/v1/tokens/bearer"',
  authResponse: AuthResponse {
    token: Token {
      realmId: '',
      token_type: '',
      access_token: '',
      refresh_token: '',
      expires_in: 0,
      x_refresh_token_expires_in: 0,
      id_token: '',
      latency: 60000,
      createdAt: 1611935355498
    },
    response: '',
    body: '',
    json: null,
    intuit_tid: ''
  },
  intuit_tid: '',
  originalMessage: 'Unable to connect to "https://oauth.platform.intuit.com/oauth2/v1/tokens/bearer"',
  error_description: ''
}
```

Comment: not sure i am following fully. Where are you storing the refresh token when app is running within lambda? Lambda new function is instantiated for every cal and even global memory is wiped off after 15 minutes of inactivity. Typically we should store refresh token outside the lambda , somewhere like DynamoDb and fetch it from there every time.

Comment: I am storing the refresh token in a JSON file located in the Lambda, in my gist you can see I read it like so: const dataFile = path.join(__dirname, '../../data/refreshToken.json'); I could easily store it in a DB

Comment: yes.. but the new refresh token you are storing it back to to disk which will be erased off after 15 minutes, Each time lambda starts it uses the same old refresh token from the deployed zip file.

Comment: Thank you for your insight, I am refactoring to save to the database at this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From comments:
Lambda container will be destroyed after few minutes of inactivity and any changes made to disk or global memory, will not be persisted across invocations after this idle period or even in other threads.

In current example Quickbooks refresh token stored in disk and will not be persisted and refresh token from original lambda zip will be used in subsequent invocations.